# Getting an error on Ruby on Rails Flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following code to display the contents of the flash object in Rails:

```
     <%= flash.each do |k, v| %>
       <div class="flash <%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
     <% end %>
```

Instead of showing just the message (or lack there of) it gives me the contents of the flash hash:

```
    {:error=>"Invalid email/password combination."}
```

or just this if there is no flash object created

```
    {}
```

Is there something wrong in my Rails code, or perhaps something wrong in my Apache setup (it doesn't appear when I push to Heroku)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with `<%` instead of `<%=` for the each loop):

```
 <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
   <div class="flash <%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
 <% end %>
```